# Missing argument 2 for {closure}();

Tags: php, web-services, rest, slim

I am in the process of working my RESTful Web Service with Slim Framework, and I got this error when I try to get data from 3 tables.

this is the function in my class:

```
public function getCard($card_id, $card_type_id, $user_id) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT uc.id, c.card_name, ct.category, c.card_desc, c.card_picture ,c.status, c.created_at from cards c, user_cards uc, cards_type ct WHERE c.card_type_id = ct.card_type_id AND c.card_id = uc.card_id AND uc.user_id = ?");

    if ($stmt == FALSE) {
        die($this->conn->error);
    } else {
        $stmt->bind_param("iii", $card_id, $card_type_id, $user_id);
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $res = array();
            $stmt->bind_result($id, $card_name, $category, $card_desc, $card_picture, $status, $created_at);

            $stmt->fetch();
            $res["id"]           = $id;
            $res["card_name"]    = $card_name;
            $res["category"]     = $category;
            $res["card_desc"]    = $card_desc;
            $res["card_picture"] = $card_picture;
            $res["status"]       = $status;
            $res["created_at"]   = $created_at;
            $stmt->close();
            return $res;
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the code in index.php:

```
$app->get('/cards/users/:card_id', 'authenticate', function($card_id, $card_type_id) {
    global $user_id;
    $response = array();
    $db       = new Card();

    // fetch card
    $result = $db->getCard($card_id, $card_type_id, $user_id);

    if ($result != NULL) {
        $response["error"]        = false;
        $response["id"]           = $result["id"];
        $response["card_name"]    = $result["card_name"];
        $response["category"]     = $result["category"];
        $response["card_desc"]    = $result["card_desc"];
        $response["card_picture"] = $result["card_picture"];
        $response["status"]       = $result["status"];
        $response["createdAt"]    = $result["created_at"];
        echoRespnse(200, $response);
    } else {
        $response["error"]   = true;
        $response["message"] = "The requested resource doesn't exists";
        echoRespnse(404, $response);
    }
});
```

Did i write something wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this line:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT uc.id, c.card_name, ct.category, c.card_desc, c.card_picture ,c.status, c.created_at from cards c, user_cards uc, cards_type ct WHERE c.card_type_id = ct.card_type_id AND c.card_id = uc.card_id AND uc.user_id = ?");
```

The query might be hard to see, so I'll format just the query:

```
SELECT uc.id, 
       c.card_name, 
       ct.category, 
       c.card_desc, 
       c.card_picture, 
       c.status, 
       c.created_at 
FROM   cards c, 
       user_cards uc, 
       cards_type ct 
WHERE  c.card_type_id = ct.card_type_id 
       AND c.card_id = uc.card_id 
       AND uc.user_id = ?
```

Notice that it only has **one** question mark, indicating that you should only bind **one** parameter to your prepared statement.

So you should change this line:

```
$stmt->bind_param("i", $user_id); //have only one argument
```

Comment: I already tried your way but I got error too because I wrote this code on my class : public function getCard($card_id, $card_type_id, $user_id) {

Comment: Check out the query, there's only one question mark, so you can only bind one param to it. See if this works.

Comment: already solved :) I adding this query too 'uc.id = ?' :)  thanks for helping me :)